# Why is "unsigned int ui = {-1};" a narrowing conversion error?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, language-lawyer, narrowing

The Standard at § 8.5.4/7 explains what a *narrowing conversion* is:

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion
>
> — from a floating-point type to an integer type, or
>
> — from long double to double or float, or from double to float, except where the source is a constant
> expression and the actual value after conversion is within the range of values that can be represented
> (even if it cannot be represented exactly), or
>
> — from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to a floating-point type, except where the source
> is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion will fit into the target type and will
> produce the original value when converted back to the original type, or
>
> — from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the
> values of the original type, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after
> conversion will fit into the target type and will produce the original value when converted back to the
> original type.

It then disallows such conversions in some list-initialization contexts, giving
examples:

> [ Note: As indicated above, such conversions are not allowed at the top level in list-initializations. — end
> note ] [ Example:

```
int x = 999;        // x is not a constant expression
const int y = 999;
const int z = 99;
char c1 = x;    // OK, though it might narrow (in this case, it does narrow)
char c2{x};     // error: might narrow
char c3{y};     // error: narrows (assuming char is 8 bits)
char c4{z};     // OK: no narrowing needed
unsigned char uc1 = {5};    // OK: no narrowing needed
unsigned char uc2 = {-1};   // error: narrows
unsigned int ui1 = {-1};    // error: narrows
signed int si1 =
{ (unsigned int)-1 };   // error: narrows
int ii = {2.0};         // error: narrows
float f1 { x };         // error: might narrow
float f2 { 7 };         // OK: 7 can be exactly represented as a float
int f(int);
int a[] =
{ 2, f(2), f(2.0) }; // OK: the double-to-int conversion is not at the top level
```

> — end example ]

All 7 of the errors illustrated by the examples are reported as such by
clang 3.2/3.3 with `-std=c++11`, e.g.

```
error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'char' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
```

None of them are reported as errors by gcc 4.7.2/4.8.1, but in each case
a similar warning is given, e.g.

```
warning: narrowing conversion of ‘x’ from ‘int’ to ‘char’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
```

(so gcc seems to know what compliance requires but opts to tolerate non-compliance
by default.)

What I do not understand is how the example:

```
unsigned int ui1 = {-1};    // error: narrows
```

qualifies as an example. (Likewise with the symmetrical `si1` example.) Evidently
the only words by which it *might* qualify as example are those of the fourth
and final item in the definition of *narrowing conversion* given above; but
if so then why does the example not escape by the qualification
*except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after
conversion will fit into the target type and will produce the original value when converted back to the
original type*? Surely `-1` there is an integer constant and, if converted to `unsigned` and back,
still yields `int -1`?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Surely -1 there is an integer constant and, if converted to unsigned and back, still yields int -1?

This is wrong. If you convert -1 to `unsigned` you get `UINT_MAX`. This is fine because converting to unsigned types is always defined. However, `UINT_MAX` does not fit in `int` and conversions to signed types are only defined by the standard when the value fits in the target type.

Comment: Specifically, such conversions yield an implementation-defined result. Converting `UINT_MAX` to `int` *typically* yields `-1`, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Does "UINT_MAX does not fit in int" mean "UINT_MAX could use more bits than int"?

Comment: @MikeKinghan. No. It means that `UINT_MAX` is outside the range of values representable with `int`.

Comment: However, when I look into the latest draft, I don't see the back-conversion check anymore. Which makes me think that `unsigned i = { -1 };` is valid C++14 code.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb The example in N3690 - yes, examples are non-normative, but nevertheless - still has `unsigned int ui1 = {-1}; // error: narrows`.

Comment: @cases ah, only integral promotions are allowed.