# Are narrowing conversions in non-type template parameters required to be diagnosed?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

This is almost assuredly a duplicate of [Is gcc wrong not diagnose narrowing conversions in non-type template arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559165/is-gcc-wrong-not-diagnose-narrowing-conversions-in-non-type-template-arguments) but it does not provide a satisfactory answer. The answer doesn't address whether or not GCC is wrong in not providing a diagnostic, only giving a warning flag that's somewhat a substitute.

The relevant sections of the standard:

§ 14.3.2/5

> For a non-type template-parameter of integral or enumeration type,
>   conversions permitted in a con- verted constant expression (5.19) are
>   applied.

§ 5.19/3

> A converted constant expression of type T is a literal constant
>   expression, implicitly converted to type T, where the implicit
>   conversion (if any) is permitted in a literal constant expression and
>   the implicit conversion sequence contains only user-defined
>   conversions, lvalue-to-rvalue conversions (4.1), integral promotions
>   (4.5), and integral conversions (4.7) other than narrowing conversions
>   (8.5.4)

The standard addresses situations in which narrowing conversions will make a program ill-formed, but there is a glaring omission here, so compilers disagree (GCC provides no diagnostic, Clang makes this an error, MSVC also provides no diagnostic.) Is there language in the standard that says for this situation, a diagnostic is required (i.e. it's ill-formed)?

```
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, -1> a;
}
```

Comment: The passages you cite appear to indicate pretty clearly that the program is indeed ill-formed; what is this "glaring omission" of which you speak? There's a [GCC bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57891) mentioned in the comments to the SO question you cite. Also, a warning is, technically, a diagnostic.

Comment: @Igor I'm aware of the bug report, but it hasn't really gone anywhere. It's not even assigned to anybody. The warning flag you have to explicitly enable is `-Wsign-conversion`, whereas Clang explicitly says that it's a non-type template parameter with a narrowing conversion. Depending on your build of GCC, it may error out because the resulting size is too big for a variable, not because of the narrowing conversion. But anyway, the question's been answered.

Comment: `I'm aware of the bug report, but it hasn't really gone anywhere` Perhaps, but what makes SO a suitable venue for airing this grievance? How is it expected to help move the bug report somewhere?

Comment: @Igor Not necessarily. It may contain more information, such as feedback from the developers whether or not they think it's a bug, or providing more standard references as Jerry has done.  Otherwise, it's left open in the air.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of n3337, the wording had already been changed to make it clear that the result is ill-formed. (§14.3.2/5):

> The following conversions are performed on each expression used as a non-type template-argument. If a non-type template-argument cannot be converted to the type of the corresponding template-parameter then the program is ill-formed.

Since it specifies that the program is ill-formed, and doesn't give specific permission to the contrary, a diagnostic is required for violating this (per §1.4/1):

> The set of diagnosable rules consists of all syntactic and semantic rules in this International Standard except for those rules containing an explicit notation that “no diagnostic is required” or which are described as resulting in “undefined behavior.”

FWIW, note that they've also separated the definition of the permissible conversions from those for converted constant expressions--the possible conversions are now listed directly in §14.3.2/5.