# Non type template argument compiles in msvc but not in clang and gcc

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, class-template, non-type-template-parameter

I am learning about non-type template parameters using *C++ Primer 5th edition* and came to know that:

> A nontype parameter may be an integral type, or a pointer or (lvalue) reference to an object or to a function type. An argument bound to a nontype integral parameter must be a constant expression.

Now to further clear my concept and confirm that I've understood the topic correctly, I wrote the following program that compiles with msvc but not with clang. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7azG46E7G)

```
#include <iostream>

template<char N> class S
{
public:
    S() 
    { 
        std::cout << "char template" << std::endl; 
    }
};

int main()
{
    S<128> s1; //MSVC compiles this but gcc and clang rejects   
}
```

So **my question is** which compiler is right here(if any). I tried to look this up in the book itself but I couldn't figure out whether the program is valid according to the c++ standard. MSVC compiles this while gcc and clang says:

```
error: non-type template argument evaluates to 128, which cannot be narrowed to type 'char'
```

Comment: This is invalid because conversion from int `128` to `char` is a narrowing conversion(since msvc, gcc and clang all uses `char` as signed). You can try `char ch{128};` and you'll get the error with msvc also. So definitely a [msvc bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-compiles-invalid-narrowing-conversi/10177081).

Comment: Dup of [Are narrowing conversions in non-type template parameters required to be diagnosed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309910/are-narrowing-conversions-in-non-type-template-parameters-required-to-be-diagnos)

Answer (score 1):

The program is **ill-formed** and *msvc is wrong in accepting the code* because the conversion from integer literal `128` to `char` is a *narrowing conversion* which is not permitted in this context as explained below. Basically this fails for the same reason that `char ch{128};` fails which is that both of these involve integral conversion with narrowing conversion.

From [temp.arg.nontype#2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg.nontype#2):

> A template-argument for a non-type template-parameter **shall be a converted constant expression** of the type of the template-parameter.

Now from [converted constant expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#def:expression,converted_constant):

> **4)** A converted constant expression of type T is an expression, implicitly converted to type T, where the converted expression is a constant expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains only
>
> **4.7)** **integral conversions other than narrowing conversions**

But note the integral conversion from int `128` to `char` is a narrowing conversion as can be seen from [narrowing conversion](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#def:narrowing_conversion):

> **7)** A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion
>
> **7.4)** from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, **except where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral promotions will fit into the target type**.

(emphasis mine)

Thus in case `char` is signed, the integral conversion from int `128` to `char` involves narrowing conversion and so is not allowed(not a converted constant expression) and hence msvc is wrong in accepting the code.

Here is the msvc bug report:

[MSVC compiles invalid narrowing conversion in nontype template argument](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-compiles-invalid-narrowing-conversi/10177081)